# fpgrowth error in R

Tags: r, apriori, fpgrowth

I am trying to fit a fpgrowth model on a in-built data set called Adult. While fitting a model, I was getting an error as shown below.

```
Error in .jcall(jPruning, "[[Ljava/lang/String;", "fpgrowth", support,  : 
method fpgrowth with signature (DDI)[[Ljava/lang/String; not found
```

I used the below R code to fit fpgrowth model.

```
library(rCBA)
data("Adult")
Adult<-as(Adult,"transactions")
rules = rCBA::fpgrowth(Adult, support=0.001, confidence=0.5, maxLength=2)
```

What's wrong with the above code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in `rCBA`. Please report the bug as an issue at https://github.com/jaroslav-kuchar/rCBA

Answer (score 0):

you must specify your "class" or consequent

`rules = rCBA::fpgrowth(Adult, support=0.001, confidence=0.5, maxLength=2, consequent="Species")`

Try with This:
https://rdrr.io/cran/rCBA/src/R/fpgrowth.R